# Let $P$ be the set of all polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ such that $p(t) = t$. Is $P$ a subspace of $P_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P$ be the set of all polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ such that $p(t) = t$. Is $P$ a subspace of $P_3$?

I'm not really sure how to solve this. I know that I have to prove that:

> Since $p, q \in P_3$, $kp \in P_3$ and $p + q \in P_3$ in order for $p$ to be a
>   subspace of $P_3$. And there needs to be a zero vector for $p$.
>
> $p(t) = a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + a_3t^3$
>
> $q(t) = b_0 + b_1t + b_2t^2 + b_3t^3$
>
> $(p+q)(t)= (a_0 + b_0) + (a_1 + b_1)t + (a_2 + b_2)t^2 + (a_3 + b_3)t^3$

Can anyone help me with this question? I'm really confused on sub-spaces.

Comment: The question is oddly phrased.  If $t$ is the indeterminate, then $P$ consists of exactly one polynomial, so that can't be right.  Maybe $t$ is a specific number, like $p(5)=5$?

Comment: Nope, it's p(t)=t, nothing else. What is stated above is the exact question I received.

Comment: @MelissaLam, it still is an unclearly posted question, never mind who wrote it and who got it.

Comment: Well the title of this question is word-by-word the exact one I received, so the rest is purely speculation on my part. What confuses you/is unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $p(t)=t$ is in your space $P$ but $2p$ isn't, as $2p(t)=2t \neq t$. So $P$ isn't a vector space.

Comment: So I'm trying to prove p(t)=t? Alright, thanks. But what about p + q ∈ P3 part of the proof?

Comment: @MelissaLam: This shows that this isn't a subspace. Even p+p isn't in the space $P$.

Comment: So p + p = t + t => 2t =/= t?

Comment: @MelissaLam: $2t \neq$t is true anyways. So that implies that $2p \$ is not in $P$, and hence $P$ isn't a subspace.